# SQL Server get result in JSON format

Tags: node.js, sql-server

```js
    app.get("/data", (req, res) => {
    request = new Request("SELECT school_roll_number, one_time_token, is_used, roll_number, name, county FROM [dbo].[school_token] JOIN [dbo].[primary_schools] ON school_roll_number = roll_number",
        function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
    var result = "";
    request.on('row', function (columns) {
        columns.forEach(function (column) {
            if (column.value === null) {
                console.log('NULL');
            } else {
                result += column.value + " ";
            }
        });
        console.log(result);
        result = "";
    });

    request.on('done', function (rowCount, more) {
        console.log(rowCount + ' rows returned');
    });
    connection.execSql(request);
});
```

Hello Im, new to react and node js

When I run these in postman, my console log will return all the list, however in postman it return no JSON body.

I'm trying to grab result in JSON format, so that I can pass it in my frontend.

Comment: If you want SQL Server to pass back JSON data, use `FOR JSON`.

Comment: I tried using this, but it just return 3267 

app.get("/data", (req, res) => {
    request = new Request("SELECT school_roll_number, one_time_token, is_used, roll_number, name, county FROM [dbo].[school_token] JOIN [dbo].[primary_schools] ON school_roll_number = roll_number",
        function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
            res.end(JSON.stringify(result)); // Result in JSON format
        });



    connection.execSql(request);
});

Comment: *"I tried using this"* There's no `FOR JSON` in that query?

Comment: Can you point me where to add FOR JSON

Comment: [Format Query Results as JSON with FOR JSON (SQL Server)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: I added for json here 

  request = new Request("SELECT DISTINCT county from [dbo].[primary_schools] ORDER by county FOR JSON AUTO",
        function (err, recordsets) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
            res.end(JSON.stringify(recordsets));
        });


Output in postman shows number of data found which is 28


Expected value is JSON format